Does $(X_n)^2$ converges in $L^1$ to $X^2$ implies $X_n$ converges to $X$ in $L^2$?
I have learned from my probability course that 
$X_n$ converges in $L^1$ to X and X in $L^{1}$ iff. $X_n$ converges in probability to X and $(X_{n})$ uniformly integrable. 

However from the link math stackexchange I know that the argument 
$X_n$ converges in $L^p$ to X and X in $L^{p}$ iff. $X_{n}$ converges in probability to $X_{n}$ and $(X_{n}^p)$ uniformly integrable 
is also true.

I am wondering the connection between these two argument. Suppose we have the right side of argument one, then $X_{n}^p$ converges in probability to $X_{n}^p$, and (from argument one) we could derive that $X_{n}^p$ converges in $L^1$ to $X_{n}^p$, but does it imply that X converges in $L^{p}$ to X? Taking p=2, I could neither prove it, nor give out a counterexample.
Thanks.

By the way, is the reverse argument true? i.e if $X_n$ converges to X in $L^2$, does $X_{n}^2$ converges to $X^2$ in $L^1$?

This looks to be untrue if $X_n\equiv 1$ and $X \equiv -1$.

To answer your comment (@Nightraidtown), if $X=0$ it's obviously true, so I can imagine that it's true in general, but it's just a supposition, and I have no time right now to think about it. But interesting question. I'll try to think about it later.

@Surb If you write $\vert X_n^2-X^2\vert=\vert X_n -X\vert \cdot \vert X_n +X\vert$, shouldn't it follow from Applying Holder and then Minkowski? At least assuming that $X_n,X\in L^2$.

Very quickly (for the question in the comment) :
$$X_n^2-X^2=(X_n-X)(X_n+X),$$
and thus, by Cauchy-Schwartz
$$\mathbb E\big[|X_n^2-X^2|\big]\leq \sqrt{\mathbb E\big[|X_n-X|^2\big]}\sqrt{\mathbb E\big[|X_n+X|^2\big]}.$$
Notice that $$\mathbb E\big[(X_n+X)^2\big]=\mathbb E\big[|X_n|^2+|X|^2+2X_nX\big].$$
Using Cauchy-Schwartz again and the fact that $\mathbb E[X_n^2]$ is bounded, you get that $\mathbb E\big[(X_n+X)^2\big]$ is also bounded, and thus $X_n^2\to X^2$ in $L^1$.
